# Fechar arquivo em C

Tags: c

Como eu faço para fechar um arquivo em C?

```
int main()
{
    abrirArquivo();
    fecharArquivo();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void abrirArquivo(){

     FILE *arquivo = fopen("pub.in", "r");// testa se o arquivo foi aberto com sucesso

      if(arquivo != NULL)
        printf("Arquivo foi aberto com sucesso.");
      else
        printf("Nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo.");

      printf("\n\n");
}
void fecharArquivo(){
      //Não estou sabendo o que digitar
}
```

O arquivo está sendo aberto, mas agora não estou sabendo fechá-lo.

Answer (score 3):

Todo arquivo deve ser fechado para a liberação de recursos quando o mesmo não for mais necessário, para isso deve utilizar a função `fclose`, declarada no cabeçalho `stdio.h`.
Sendo o prototipo: `int fclose (FILE * arquivo_aberto);`.

Sabendo disso seu código deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
        #include <stdio.h>    
        int main()
        {
            abrirArquivo();
            fecharArquivo();
        
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
        void abrirArquivo(){
        
             FILE *arquivo = fopen("pub.in", "r");// testa se o arquivo foi aberto com sucesso
        
              if(arquivo != NULL)
                printf("Arquivo foi aberto com sucesso.");
              else
                printf("Nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo.");
        
              printf("\n\n");
        }
        void fecharArquivo(FILE * arquivo){
              if(fclose(arquivo) == 0) //Função fclose retorna zero em sucesso, um não zero caso contrário
                printf("Arquivo fechado com sucesso.");
              else
                printf("Erro");
        }
```

PS: lembre-se que o arquivo deve ser passado entre as chamadas de funções, pois o ponteiro do tipo FILE aponta para um arquivo único